# JDBI mapper JUnit tests

Tags: junit, mapper, jdbi

I'd like to unit test my JDBI mapper classes since not all do trivial property mapping.

My testing class looks as follows:

```
  public class IdentRuleMapperTest {

  @Mock
  ResultSet resultSet;

  @Mock
  ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData;

  @Mock
  StatementContext ctx;

  IdentRuleMapper mapper;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    mapper = new IdentRuleMapper();
  }

  @Test
  public void mapTest() throws SQLException {
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("ID")).thenReturn("The ID");
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("NAME")).thenReturn("The name");
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("REGULATION")).thenReturn("CRS");
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("JSON_ACTIONS_STRING")).thenReturn("the json string");
    IdentRule identRule = mapper.map(0, resultSet, ctx);

  }
}
```

The test throws NPE on the line

`Mockito.when(resultSet.getString("ID")).thenReturn("The ID");`

Anyone can point out to me why this won't work?

Comment: Guess: Did you use `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to make sure the ResultSet annotation is evaluated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The annotation `@Mock` does not create the mock objects by itself. You have to add [Mockito's JUnit](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html) rule as a field to your test

```
@Rule
public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
```

or use its [JUnit runner](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class IdentRuleMapperTest {
  ...
```

or create the mocks in an `@Before` method using [MockitoAnnotations](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html)

```
@Before
public void initMocks() {
  MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when setting the expectations on mock objects, use Matchers for arguments matching.

```
Mockito.when(resultSet.getString( Matchers.eq("ID"))).thenReturn("The ID");
```